# How to call aysnc function getAffiliatesCodes() inside other async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, loopbackjs

this is the first function , i have this function getAffliateCodesAsync() my requirement is to call this method from inside other function (function -2 >> generateCriBodyWithCreParameter(..))
and pass the returning value of  >>(function-1) getAffliateCodesAsync(), into the third function and use that value in (function -3) checkLessorMagnitudeCode(..) and use the returning value of function-2 in function-3 at place where codeList is used, Please help

```
//function-1.

async function getAffliateCodesAsync(){
  console.debug("==AFFILIATE_CODES==");
  const ApplicationParameter = loopback.getModel('ApplicationParameter');
  const applicationParamFieldValue = await ApplicationParameter.find({
      where: {
        fieldName: 'AFFILIATE_CODES'
      },
      fields: ['fieldValue']
  });
  return (applicationParamFieldValue.length)? applicationParamFieldValue.map(entity => String(entity['fieldValue'])):[];
}

//2.function-2
const generateCriBodyWithCreParameter = (positions, lotNumber, cutOffDate) => {
  const CreParameter = loopback.getModel('CreParameter');
  let creId = 1;
  const positionData = [];
  const content = [];
  return CreParameter.find()
  .then((creParameterList) => {
    const promises = positions.map((position) => {
      const cutOffDatePreviousMonth = getCutOffDatePreviousMonth(position.accountingDate);
      return positionNativeProvider.getPositionInformationForPreviousCutOffDateForCriApf(
        position, cutOffDatePreviousMonth)
        .then((positionRetrieved) => {
          const positionLowerCase = _.mapKeys(position, (value, key) => _.toLower(key)); 
          const creParameters = _.filter(creParameterList, {
            flowType: 'MI',
            event: 'POSITION',
            liabilityAmortizationMethod: position.liabilityAmortizationMethod
          });
          for (const creParameter of creParameters) {
            const atollAmountValue = getAtollAmountValue(positionLowerCase, creParameter);
            if (atollAmountValue && matchSigns(atollAmountValue, creParameter.amountSign)) {
              const lineGenerated = checkContractLegalStatusForCri(position, creParameter,
                atollAmountValue, content, creId, lotNumber, cutOffDate, positionRetrieved);
              //No Line is generated in this case so the creId must not incremente
              if (lineGenerated !== -1) {
                positionData.push({
                  positionId: position.id,
                  creId
                });
                creId++;
              }
            }
          }
        });
   });
   return Promise.all(promises)
   .then(() => {
     return {
       contentCreBody: content.join('\n'),
       positionData
     };
   });
 });
};
//function -3
const checkLessorMagnitudeCode = (lessorMagnitudeCode,codeList=[]) => {
  if (!lessorMagnitudeCode) return false;
  if (_.size(lessorMagnitudeCode) === 5 &&
    (_.startsWith(lessorMagnitudeCode, 'S') || _.startsWith(lessorMagnitudeCode, 'T'))  
    && codeList.includes(lessorMagnitudeCode)) {
      return true;
    }
  return false;
};
```

//above codelist where I want to use the returning value

Comment: const codeList = getAffliateCodesAsync();
lessorMagnitudeCode(codeList)
//when i am calling like this inside the second-2 function generateCriBodyWithCreParameter(...) i am getting promise in codeList but i want value in codeList and want to pass that value in function-3 >> lessorMagnitudeCode(codeList)

Comment: use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)